# Combine seperate images into a single image using HTML tags

Tags: html

I have 3 parts of images and I have to display it as single image and also want to include the links to the 3 parts of images using HTML tags.

I created the table with 1 column and 2 rows and I inserted the images into the 3 section of the table. But it have some spaces between the upper and the lower images (1st and 2nd row). How can resolve this problem and create a single graphic without any spaces and also need to include link into the 3rd image.

Need help urgently

```
<table style="width: 660px; border-collapse: collapse; height: 237px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" sizset="0" sizcache="15">
<tbody sizset="0" sizcache="15">
<tr>
<td><img style="margin: 0px; border: 0px currentColor;" src="uploaded/Online_Newsletters/Nav/masthead-ball_top.jpg" width="665" height="197"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img style="margin: 0px; border: 0px currentColor;" src="uploaded/Online_Newsletters/Nav/ball_bottom_left.jpg" width="579" height="37"><img style="margin: 0px; border: 0px currentColor;" src="uploaded/Online_Newsletters/Nav/ball_bottom_right.jpg" width="86" height="37"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I used the above code but still have space between the images. In my company website is managed using finalsite, so I am using the finalsite editor for this one.

Comment: It would help if you could post the code you have so far - preferably into http://jsfiddle.net/ — so that we can see it. You might want to try setting the images to `display: block` using CSS, but it’s hard to tell from your question as it stands.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wLA3T/1/-  the link for the code

Comment: @PaulD.Waite At almost 20K rep, you should know that was not an answer, but a comment.

Comment: @casperOne: sure — I was thinking the OP might have updated the question quickly, thus making it easier to just write an answer and update it once some code was posted. I agree the content I posted was appropriate for a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use cellpadding and cellspacing in your table tag:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
```

and to use the 3rd image as link just use

```
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="yourimage.jpg" border="0" style="float:left;" /></a>
```

EDIT:

Add `style="float:left;"` to your img tags.

http://jsfiddle.net/H628X/1/

Comment: You may also need to look at the border-collapse:collapse; css attribute which will collapse the borders around each cell in the table.

Comment: Or we set border="0" so that we don't have any borders which prevent to display the parts of the image as one :)

Comment: Doesn't always work, I will try and dig up an example later, and it may just be certain browsers, but setting cellpadding cellspacing and border to 0 isnt sufficient to get rid of the gap between cells in all cases.  There is sometimes a need for the border-collapse too.

Comment: So to be on the save side we need to use all? `cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;"`

Comment: To be honest it was probably bad coding on my part a while back, I just remember having real trouble with one particular website I was making at the time.  I am not 100% sure if it is needed, I know border-collapse collapses the borders of neighbouring cells into 1 border, so it may be that setting border=0 on individual cells or rows may solve the issue? I am not that current with html and css though.  I will try it out later and update here as required.

Comment: I will later, im at work at the moment so don't have it to hand.

Comment: hehe I meant user1487320 to post the code, but he deleted his comment after he posted code :D

Answer (score 0):

Along with the @Wolv3r answer, if you do not have

```
img {
   display:block;
}
```

Inlined or using style tags, this causes issues in gmail / yahoo.

Source for good html for emailing methods:

http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails/